# Facebook GraphAPI

Tags: asp.net

I am getting this error in using  Graph api for facebook

"error": {
"type": "OAuthException",
"message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration."
}
}

I want to use localhost for developing website facebook application using the graph api. i working in asp.net c#

My Callback_URL public const string CALLBACK_URL = "http://localhost/FB_Conn/default.aspx";

In my developer Facebookapp:

WebsitSite URL: 
http://localhost:3915/

Any suggestions 
Thanks
SC

Please help with this..
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify "some.another.domain.name" in your `hosts` file and specify the same in the fb application settings.

Comment: I changed the SiteURL to http://localhost/ instead of http://localhost/3915. Now IE has this error.. Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage Diagonose connection

Comment: I tried changing the hosts file It did not help. But it says IE cannot diagnose the connection.. and Firefox unable to find local host

Comment: @user575219: this trouble has nothing to do with facebook